# PTIJ: Why use Mashgichim when Hashem has Hashgacha Pratis and is the most qualified?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Hashem oversees ***everything*** in the universe, from the smallest singular quarks to the massive black holes ripping each other apart. There is constant Hashgacha Pratis being administered, so why do we rely on human Mashgichim?

If we just used Hashem as a Mashgiach, there wouldn't be any mistakes made, no need for cameras, everything would be watched 24/7, workers wouldn't be able to Treif anything up, and Mashgichim would finally not have to deal with abusive store owners, davening by themselves, or minimizing their Yom Tov joy to be stuck in a kitchen!

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: No that is not quite right. Hashem's hashgocho is not reliable he allows mistakes to be made. tsadkim.... uposhim ... The translation of hashgocho is watching not making sure no mistakes are made. Many mashgichim also rely on the literal translation and do no more than watch. I suppose you could say their excuse is they copy hashem.

Comment: https://www.jpost.com/Israel-News/Hashgacha-Pratit-threatens-to-sue-Safeds-chief-rabbi-NGO-over-kashrut-slack-508103

Comment: I can't believe there's an ACTUAL organization that dares call themselves that!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a famous joke that goes like this: A big tzadik dies and goes up to heaven. When he gets there, there's a huge feast being served. There are delicacies galore. Anything you could ever want is being served, and the host of the feast is none other than the Creator of Heaven and Earth, HaKadosh Baruch Hu himself. The tzadik is beside himself with excitement. He takes a seat at the table and peruses a menu with excitement while he waits for a waiter to come to take his order. When the waiter comes, the man says, "This feast looks fantastic! Could you please tell me, under whose hashgacha is this amazing spread?" The waiter replies, "Sir, this is Olam HaBa. We are in the presence of HaShem and he himself ensures that everything is up to the kosher standards he has given us in the Torah." The tzadik nervously replies, "Thank you for that information. I will have the fruit plate, please."

The fact of the matter is that the standards of HaShem's hashgacha, as published in the Torah, are not up to the stringent halakhic standards the sophisticated kosher consumer demands. Glatt Kosher? He never said anything about that. Not to mention the chicken and cheese combinations. If we want to ensure that we're only eating foods that meet the highest levels of kashrus, we must rely on human mashgichim.

Answer (score 2):

There is one specific areas of kashrut that requires human intervention.

The *batul beshishim* principle was based on taste. Does the milk impart a milky taste to the meat or does the meat impart a meaty taste to the dairy dish? God has no taste. Well, actually, He has extremely **good** taste in choosing the Jewish people, but, in terms of tasting dairy and meaty food, these concepts don't apply to him. Thus, you would need human involvement.

But of greater concern is that there are thousands of mashgichim throughout the world whose employment and sole source of income depends on hashgacha. You would be eliminating all these jobs and create tremendous poverty. It's not good for the economy.

Another angle to consider. If you left all of the supervision to God, this would be what is called *hashgacha pratit* - private hashgacha. That's good in situations where an individual needs specific help out of a tough situation, or Hashem wants to be benevolent and protect someone. But, the point is, that such hashgacha is private and geared for the individual.

The concept of *hashgacha pratit* couldn't apply to food products available for public use. It wouldn't be *pratit* - private- would it?